# How to prevent "screen -dmS sessionName program.sh" from disappearing after program.sh finishes?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, gnu-screen

If I run rsync inside `screen`, then after a while I can login to the server and attach the detached `screen`.

Now I want to run rsync from `crontab`. I added this entry to crontab:

```
03 19 * * *     root /usr/bin/screen -dmS rsyncSess uptime
```

After crontab executes the command, I run `screen -ls` but nothing is listed.

After I run `/usr/bin/screen -dmS rsyncSess watch -n 5 uptime` I can see that session when run `screen -ls`.

How can I run a script in `screen` from `crontab` and then attach that screen session to see the output of rsync  (even after rsync is finished)?

Until now I found [this tread](https://askubuntu.com/a/15291).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you:

- run `screen -ls` as the same user that is used by crontab to start your command
- use a main command that doesn't end before you reattach, since that will end your session as well. If you run a short command and want the session to persist, use something like `bash -c 'short_command; exec bash'` (or, as pointed out in the [link you mention](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15244/how-can-i-create-a-cron-command-that-will-execute-a-command-inside-a-detached-sc/15291#15291), add `defzombie ZZ` to your `.screenrc`).